# Where to put data with single values that are changeable

Tags: mysql, database

I'm developing a portal for a school and I'm having second thoughts on where to put data such as history, mission & vision, etc. I can easily just create separate tables for each, but I don't think it's an efficient way to do it, since they'll only contain single data. Is it okay to create a table that contains only a single row? Another solution in my mind is to create a table that may contain ALL data that have a single data, but I think it would hurt maintainability, as there would be no way of identifying which is which.

Comment: Use a table that maps names to values. E.g. `name = "mission", value = "Our missing is to..."`

Comment: Usually things like this wouldn't be put into the database at all, just put them in static web pages. If you're trying to design a CMS, you'd probably be better off using one that already exists, like Wordpress, instead of rolling your own.